# Sonarqube - Gitlab: Request was redirected, please provide the correct URL

Tags: gitlab, sonarqube, devops

When I try to make a devops integration between SonarQube and GitLab, it gives the below error: **Your request has been redirected; please provide the correct URL** (see attached *). I already gave all the permissions to gitlab-access-token, but still no luck. Is anyone aware of what could be the problem?

Sonarqube version: 9.8.0.63668 (working as docker container)

gitlab version: 11.3

[image: gitlab-sonarqube request redirected error]

Comment: *the gitlab url is: https:// gitlab.company.xxx